# htmlentities() not working when using with data from a table

Tags: php, character-encoding, collation, html-entities

I'm trying to print data from a table that contains a special character such as é. I've used the function htmlentities() hoping it solves the problem, but instead of solving the problem, the data wouldn't appear at all.

For example:

I'm supposed to print this:

> "Lightroom 3 pour les Phototographes du Numérique"

However, the character **é** appears as �. Thus using the fuction htmlentities() should logically solve the problem. Yet whilst using it with a string that contains the character **é** nothing prints but an empty space. Using the function on a string that contains no special character works fine.

> "Lightroom 3 pour les Phototographes du Num**e**rique"

prints as it is, while

> "Lightroom 3 pour les Phototographes du Num**é**rique"

prints as

> " "

My databse and all the tables are UTF-8 encoded, as well as my html document.

Comment: If you are using UTF-8 everywhere then **you don't need HTML entities** to display accented characters. You're most likely failing to use/declare UTF-8 properly somewhere in your flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) documentation, it says that

> If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the given encoding an empty string will be returned, unless either the ENT_IGNORE or ENT_SUBSTITUTE flags are set.

As suggested in the doc, you can try to force the encoding (maybe "ISO-8859-1" or "ISO-8859-15")?

Comment: Using ISO-8859-1 works well in my case.

Comment: Glad to see it resolve your issue, but as @Álvaro González suggested, **'you don't need HTML entities'**, you have to check [UTF8 How to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) to see where in your files, **'you fail to use/decalre UTF8 properly'**

Comment: If using `ISO-8859-1` fixes the problem then the base information "My databse and all the tables are UTF-8 encoded, as well as my html document" happens to be false.